# Visual Studio 2019 Design View Rendering Issue

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, winforms

My Visual Studio Enterprise Edition's Design view (When designing WPF Applications) doesn't render the window properly. specially when something in the window changes or when i scroll the design view it doesn't update correctly. window will render as displaced white boxes or lines sometimes blurred mess.(See Screenshot ) [image]

**This problem first occurred after i updated windows.**

Things  i Tried So Far

1. Rolling Back windows update to previous version and uninstall all other updates.
2. updating graphic drivers
3. updating visual studio
4. running with different Video Cards (RTX 2080/Intel 630)

but none of this things didnt fix the issue
this now happens only in wpf applications even the built application has the same issues

Comment: Did your project run successfully?What is the version of your Visual Studio 2019? Have you tried to upgrade VS to the latest version of the test?

Comment: yeah i tried all if them but nothing worked after searching whole internet i found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem only happens in .NET Core WPF Applications. If you are using a gaming laptop (MSI, ROG, Alineware) this might happen to you.

**Problem**
The problem is my realtek audio driver uses audio service called "Sonic Studio" (My Laptop is an Asus Rog) this application service interfere with .NET Core library some how (I don't know how) and causes rendering issues in both .netcore view designer and compiled applications. According my research Several Audio Services from other manufacturers also causes this issue.

In my case I had to get rid from sonic studio service. I disabled the sonic studio service called ***"Nahimic"***. It may different for your case. Or you can uninstall sonic studio. And make sure to restart your pc after that.

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2493

Answer (score 0):

I have gaming laptop. ASUS TUF Gaming.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.6.
I had to go to Tools -> Options -> choose `Dark Theme` from `Color Theme` drop down. For some reason Light theme is bugged for me. Now I can design WPF forms again. And properties toolbar renders ok too.

I also tried all combinations of change `Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance` and `Enable rich client visual experience` and `Use hardware graphics acceleration of available.`. It didn't help in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i'll check this out currently I'm using visual studio without any issues because I uninstalled the bugged audio driver.